# jQuery function not binding to newly added td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is very common problem and i read a lot about this topic. But in my example, I came to the wall. And I ask you for help. How to bind functions using jQuery handler: .on();

```
$( "td" )
    .on( "mouseenter", function() {
    $( this ).css({
    "background-color": "white"
    });
```

Link to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/epredator/7Fz6X/

After click "Add person" button there append new row in my table. But this new element has no functionality like others. Hot to fix this, thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

The first selector needs to be something that already exists on the page, then you can delegate.  For example:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', 'td', function() {
```